# How do I search for and download a file (without mentioning the URL of the file) using Python?

Tags: python, download

I found scripts where I can download a file by mentioning the URL using the module urllib.

Is there any way I can download a file by just mentioning it's name and searching the web for the said filename and downloading it?

Comment: You... you want to search through, the entire internet?

Comment: Do you want to use a search engine like Google or similar? If so, you will be required to utilize some API for this.

Comment: Well, I guess you _could_ write a search bot crawling the internet for any url ending with a given filename - I mean, it is technically possible, but I hope you are not in a hurry because it might take quite some time to run xD

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to limit your question. As you can see from the comments this is way too broad (literally!). For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

A URL is defined as a "Uniform Resource Locator". It specifies what server the file is on and the path to access it. If you don't know the location of a file on the web, the matter gets complex.

What you would need to do is:

- Retrieve a list of all registered domains on the web. For example, you could use [zonefiles.io](https://zonefiles.io/) for this, but there are many alternatives.
- Use a **web scraper** to look for all files under a certain domain. An example is [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

Then you would need to build some logic to download the wanted file: eg. download the first one you encounter? Files normally have a version number, are you getting the most recent one and skipping duplicates? Etc.

Comment: Instead of downvoting, please comment on how this answer is incorrect so that we can all learn